# How to make a hover like the one in windows 10 settings?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Can someone tell me how to do a hover like this but in css.

This is an example of windows 10 settings. But I would like to replicate it in css.

[image: Windows 10 settings hover]

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to replicate? All I see is a grid.

Comment: @Barmar The hover, to give a small border to the containers.

Comment: So create CSS for `.classname:hover` that has the `border` property that you want. WTP?

Comment: @Barmar But I want one like the one in the picture.

Comment: This kind of hover effect, as far as I know, is not possible with CSS alone. You will need JS to react to the cursor's movement.

Comment: Are you saying that what you want is for a faint white border and faint white background, both of which fade away to the right, to show when an element is hovered? Please show us  what you have tried so far, in particular we need to see the relevant HTML structure.

Comment: I found [a nice CodePen](https://codepen.io/gubb/pen/PdZqKy) that replicates this effect (with JS, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple gradient background images to get that sort of effect on hover.

Here's an example. Obviously play around with the settings until you get exactly the look you want.

```html
<style>
  body {
    background: black;
  }
  
  div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    color: red;
  }
  
  div:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, transparent), linear-gradient(white, transparent), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 20%, transparent);
    background-size: 100% 1px, 1px 100%, 100% 100%;
    background-position: top left, top left, 1px 1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div>Hover here</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I take it that you don't use Windows 10, do you? The shades change depending on where the cursor is. See [this comment of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76498224#comment134885333_76498224).